# Files are left on disk even if created with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE attribute

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a program that creates files with FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE attribute. I see rare cases, on some machines, which even if the process goes down, the file is there.

```
CreateFile(fileName,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE,
        NULL);
```

Note: I'm sure 100% no other process holds handle to these files. In addition, all handles (OpenFile, CreateFile) are created with the FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE attribute.

I'm trying to find the edge cases which the guarantee that the file will be deleted immediately after all of its handles are closed, is not working.(except unexpected shutdown of OS)
Does anyone know of other cases where file can be left on disk?

Comment: If you're not explicitly closing the handle (using `CloseHandle()`) then you should be - and checking the return status.     If you're not explicitly doing that, then some abnormal process terminations can result in the file handle not being closed (e.g. process terminated using `TerminateProcess()`).   Also, a process that is terminating "normally" may take a while to close, and any handles you haven't explicitly closed will remain open until then.

Comment: There is no guarantee, that the file were to be *"immediately"* deleted after all handles to it have been closed. At that point, the file is *marked* for deletion, which will happen at any point after that. @pet If a process terminates, no matter how, the OS will close all of its open handles.

Comment: Look, I'm explicitly closing the handle, that's not the point here. The point is to understand why OS can ignore FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE attribute. In which case it can happen? unfortunately the case is rare so I have no ability to understand what is happening at this time on the server that caused the file not to be deleted.

Comment: @Svirin "*The point is to understand why OS can ignore FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE attribute*" - it doesn't ignore that flag. But, what you describe can typically only happen if there are open handles to the file. Did you *verify* that using a tool like [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, I verified it with process explorer, I know that usually only happens if there are open handles to the file, but that is not the case, So I'm looking for some other situations to be expected for such OS behavior.

Comment: @Svirin Could you show steps and environment information for reproducing this issue?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT happens on remote machines of windows server 2019, but reproduction is so rare that it's not so possible, the point here is to understand what can cause OS not to delete the file even when there are no handles for the file.

Comment: @Svirin In normal situation, this issue doesn't happen. Even shutting down when the file is open and a process has its handle the file still is deleted by system (System terminate the process the cause all of the file's handles closed). So this issue may happen in some rare unusual situation like power loss suddenly when the system has no time to do clean up work etc.

Answer (score 1):

As comments have stated, most likely a handle is still opened on the file. However, this does not have to be the only reason why it still exists.

You could have a program that called `WriteFile` but has been force terminated (so the handle has been closed), and a pending IRP is holding the file. This IRP will not allow the file to be freed until it's reference count has reached 0 within the kernel. Because the IRP is still pending, it's nonzero.

Comment: What does IRP mean?

Comment: @MarkRansom An IRP is an I/O request packet. It’s information about an I/O operation usually sent to a driver by the IO subsystem of the Windows kernel. A pending IRP is an IRP that has not been fully processed by the driver, and its resources (the file) should not be released.